# Ping with timestamp and log

Tags: batch-file, timestamp, ping

Guys im using this script in a batch file to perform continuous ping with timestamp and to be recorded in a log file, it is working fine on my computer ( windows 8 64 bit ) but when i try to use it on a windows 7 machine also 64 bit, whenever i run the batch i keep getting that:

> Could not find C:\user\administrator\pinglog.txt

knowing that i have created the file pinglog.txt but i really cant figure out the problem.

```
@echo off
del pinglog.txt
for /f "tokens=*" %%A in ('ping localhost -n 1 ') do (echo %%A>>pinglog.txt && GOTO Ping)
:Ping
for /f "tokens=* skip=2" %%A in ('ping localhost -n 1 ') do (echo %date% %time% %%A>>pinglog.txt && GOTO Ping)
```

i appreciate any help.
Thank you in advance

Comment: is this somehow related to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35739609/how-to-add-time-stamp-in-the-beginning-of-batch-file-result)?

Comment: Edit your question and change the title related to your real issue !

Comment: Do you have administrator rights on both computers?

Comment: Add a space before `>>` If it happens to be a number then it has a redirect that filenumber effect. IE `23:04:36>>Pinlog.txt` means `23:04:3 6>>Pinglog.txt` which redirects a probable non existent filenumber 6. When you put `>>` in a batchfile CMD fixes it to `1>>`.

Comment: `:loop
    wmic /append:"textfile.txt" path win32_pingstatus where "address='127.0.0.1' and responsetime > 100" get responsetime,timestamprecord
goto loop
` That is three lines. Go here to see it formatted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35591855/writing-a-batch-file-to-detect-ping-anomalies/35591967#35591967

Comment: You could use this program  https://pacificblue.software/download/ping_log

Answer (score 5):

Over PowerShell you can use this CLI.

```
ping.exe -t 10.227.23.241 |Foreach{"{0} - {1}" -f (Get-Date),$_} >> Ping_IP.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

`Could not find C:\user\administrator\pinglog.txt` means that the file was not found. And the reason for this is really simple. The folder is called user**s** and not user. So the correct path is `C:\users\administrator\pinglog.txt`.